# Sing split in data frame by semicolon delimiter?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, delimiter

I want to split the text separated by semi-colon in a dataframe using R without using third-party packages.

I have the following data.

```
> #To view the first 6 rows of the data
> head(bank1)
  age.job.marital.education.default.housing.loan.contact.month.day_of_week.duration.campaign.pdays.previous.poutcome.emp.var.rate.cons.price.idx.cons.conf.idx.euribor3m.nr.employed.y
1                                                                      56;housemaid;married;basic.4y;no;no;no;telephone;may;mon;261;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no
2                                                               57;services;married;high.school;unknown;no;no;telephone;may;mon;149;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no
3                                                                   37;services;married;high.school;no;yes;no;telephone;may;mon;226;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no
4                                                                         40;admin.;married;basic.6y;no;no;no;telephone;may;mon;151;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no
5                                                                   56;services;married;high.school;no;no;yes;telephone;may;mon;307;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no
6                                                                  45;services;married;basic.9y;unknown;no;no;telephone;may;mon;198;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no
```

Please help me out in splitting the data into various columns according to the column names in the header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When importing data, specify `;` as field separator character. Is that an option?

Comment: Welcome to SO! how are you inporting your data in r? `read.csv`? other? If you cannot work on the inport, could you post the result of `dput(head(bank1))` instead of `head(bank1)`? This is going to make easier to copy and paste your data in R.

Comment: @markus I tried doing that. But, the headers are separated by . while the data is separated by ;

Comment: @s_t But, I have nearly 45000 rows. It will hard for me to copy paste each data, right?

Comment: @AradhyaMudigonda, you are right, that's why I've advice you to nest the `head()` in the `dput()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your `data.frame` column into the `character` string and run `read.table` once again. However please pay attention that the qty of column names (28) is not equal to qty of columns (21). Moreover delimeters for column header and observations are different (it looks like spaces for header, semicolon for observations).

Please see the code below:

```
df <- structure(list(age.job.marital.education.default.housing.loan.contact.month.day_of_week.duration.campaign.pdays.previous.poutcome.emp.var.rate.cons.price.idx.cons.conf.idx.euribor3m.nr.employed.y = structure(c(4L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("37;services;married;high.school;no;yes;no;telephone;may;mon;226;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no", 
"40;admin.;married;basic.6y;no;no;no;telephone;may;mon;151;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no", 
"45;services;married;basic.9y;unknown;no;no;telephone;may;mon;198;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no", 
"56;housemaid;married;basic.4y;no;no;no;telephone;may;mon;261;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no", 
"56;services;married;high.school;no;no;yes;telephone;may;mon;307;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no", 
"57;services;married;high.school;unknown;no;no;telephone;may;mon;149;1;999;0;nonexistent;1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;no"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

z <- paste(df[, 1], sep = "", collapse = "\n")
df2 <- read.table(text = z, header = FALSE, sep = ";")

nms2 <- unlist(strsplit(names(df), "\\."))[-(22:28)]
names(df2) <- nms2
str(df2)
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ age        : int  56 57 37 40 56 45
 $ job        : Factor w/ 3 levels "admin.","housemaid",..: 2 3 3 1 3 3
 $ marital    : Factor w/ 1 level "married": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ education  : Factor w/ 4 levels "basic.4y","basic.6y",..: 1 4 4 2 4 3
 $ default    : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","unknown": 1 2 1 1 1 2
 $ housing    : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 2 1 1 1
 $ loan       : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 2 1
 $ contact    : Factor w/ 1 level "telephone": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ month      : Factor w/ 1 level "may": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ day_of_week: Factor w/ 1 level "mon": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ duration   : int  261 149 226 151 307 198
 $ campaign   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ pdays      : int  999 999 999 999 999 999
 $ previous   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ poutcome   : Factor w/ 1 level "nonexistent": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ emp        : num  1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1
 $ var        : num  94 94 94 94 94 ...
 $ rate       : num  -36.4 -36.4 -36.4 -36.4 -36.4 -36.4
 $ cons       : num  4.86 4.86 4.86 4.86 4.86 ...
 $ price      : int  5191 5191 5191 5191 5191 5191
 $ idx        : Factor w/ 1 level "no": 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Artem

Comment: @AradhyaMudigonda Please consider to [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem.